# STL-Sort not working as expected

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I feel as though I'm using this correctly but the compiler feels otherwise. I'm trying to sort a list of courses in alphabetical order in my sort_by_name function using the stl sort algorithm. This is roughly what I've written:

```
class SomeClass {
  private:
    struct course {
        string id, name;
    };
    vector<course> COURSES;
    bool nameCmp(course a, course b) {return (a.name > b.name) ? true : false;}
  public:
    void sort_by_name() {
        sort(COURSES.begin(), COURSES.end(), nameCmp);
    }
};
```

Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<SomeClass::course>::iterator, std::vector<SomeClass::course>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the function to this:

```
static bool nameCmp(course a, course b) { return a.name > b.name; }
```

Even better would be to pass the arguments by const-reference, `course const & a` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
     bool SomeClass::nameCmp(course a, course b) {return (a.name > b.name) ? true : false;}
```

Has an implicit `SomeClass *this` parameter.  Make the method outside the class by either moving the declaration or making it `static`.

Answer (score -1):

The `sort` algorithm isn't going to call the `nameCmp` function from an object or in relation to the class, it's going to call it from the global namespace. You need to make it a free function, or make it static and use `SomeClass::nameCmp`.

Comment: No, the namespace has nothing to do with this, the reason is that a member function cannot be used as a comparer for `std::sort` because of the implicit `this` parameter.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, I think you misunderstood my point. The function won't be called from an object, as in `object->nameCmp`, and it won't be called from the class perspective as in `class::nameCmp`. Perhaps namespace was the wrong term but I don't have a better one. The implicit `this` parameter is just another way of saying called as an object member function, and a more confusing way to put it I think.

Comment: The thing is, you don't _need_ to specify the class name. You would need to in order to refer to a static method of another class, but when you're inside a method, then just the name will do. Kerrek's answer is correct.